# State of apps when Development Provisioning Profile is invalidated

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying to understand what happens to **Development apps** already installed onto devices, running with **invalidated 'Development provisioning Profile'**

And would I be able to **install a Development app** signed with **Invalid Development Provisioning Profile** onto my registered devices.

In consideration, Provisioning profile has the right App ID, Development Certificate and Devices.

I have faced a scenario where the so called **Firstly generated build was not installable** when Provisioning profile was invalidated, so edited to make it valid. Perhaps **secondly generated build was installable** though profile was invalid again.

Confused with these scenarios to consider the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

When Development profile expired/invalidated:

1. Already installed app won't be affected and It should be still working fine.
2. You can't generate new builds for devices.
3. If you generated the build with valid profile and invalidated that profile, you should generate build again once you made it valid.

Comment: Thanks @Natarajan! Referring to 3rd point, I am facing different experience as explained in the question. Both builds generated under 3rd referred point circumstance, one build is installable & works and other build doesn't. Any suggestions on that please?